# OnChange Event Stuck in Loop, Crashing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting an infinite loop / crash here.

I'm trying to get an onChange event fired for these radio buttons (which are built after pulling data from a query), but I think it keeps redrawing and I can't figure out why.

Any thoughts on how I can solve this?

```
const GetChallenge = async () => {
  const slug = useParams()
  const data = await shopifyApolloClient.query({ query: singleProduct(slug) })
  return data
}

const Challenge = () => {

  let [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
  let [product, setProduct] = useState([])
  let [variants, setVariants] = useState([])
  let [options, setOption] = useState()
  let [metafields, setMetafields] = useState([])


  GetChallenge().then((ret) => {
    setProduct(ret.data.product)
    setVariants(ret.data.product.variants.edges)
    setOption(ret.data.product.variants.edges[0].node.title)
    setMetafields(ret.data.product.metafields.edges)
    setLoaded(true)
  })

  const handleOptions = (event) => {
    setOption(event.target.value)
  }

  if (loaded === true) {

    return (
      <div>
        {variants.map((e) => (
          <label
            htmlFor={e.node.title}
            key={e.node.id}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="options"
              checked={e.node.title === options}
              value={e.node.title}
              onChange={handleOptions}
            />
            {e.node.title}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
    )

  } else {
    return (
      <p>Not Loaded</p>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: logically, if you expect `if (loaded === true) {` to be called multiple times, until it becomes true, wouldn't you *also* expect `GetChallenge().then(...)` to get called the same number of times, causing a loop of state updates? Every time the state changes, it gets called again... causing more state changes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetChallenge` is triggering every render. Try [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with the empty array empty soas to trigger only onmount.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const GetChallenge = async () => {
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        GetChallenge().then((ret) => {
            setProduct(ret.data.product)
            setVariants(ret.data.product.variants.edges)
            setOption(ret.data.product.variants.edges[0].node.title)
            setMetafields(ret.data.product.metafields.edges)
            setLoaded(true)
    }),[]}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
onChange={(event) => setOption(event.target.value)}
```